# Independence of the path implies that the fundamental group is abelian

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

a) Prove that two paths $f,g$ from $x$ to $y$ give rise to the same isomorphism from $\pi(X,x)$ to $\pi(X,y)$ (i.e. $u_f=u_g)$ if and only if $[g*\bar{f}] \in Z(\pi(X,x))$.

b) Let $u_f: \pi(X,x) \rightarrow \pi(X,y)$ be the isomorphism determined by a path $f$ from $x$ to $y$. Prove that $u_f$ is independent of $f$ if and only if $\pi(X,x)$ is abelian.

I manage to prove part a) but not part b). I prove the backward direction of part b) by using part a). Can anyone give some hints on how to prove the forward direction?

Comment: You mean "if $u_f$ is independent of $f$ then $\pi(X,x)$ is abelian"? Part a) says that the class of every loop passing through $y$ must be central.

Comment: Choosing a different path amounts to a conjugation in the  fundamental group.

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fundamental group is abelian iff the fundamental group isomorphisms (a-hat) coincide](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/269467/fundamental-group-is-abelian-iff-the-fundamental-group-isomorphisms-a-hat-coin)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $u_f$ is independent of $f$ then for any path $g$ from $x$ to $y$ we have $u_f=u_g$ and so by the first part $[g\ast \overline{f}]\in Z(\pi_1(X,x))$. Now let $[\gamma],[\gamma']\in\pi_1(X,x)$ for loops $\gamma,\gamma'$ based at $x$. Remember that $[f\ast\overline{f}]=[c]$ where $c$ is the constant loops at $x$ and so $[\gamma]=[\gamma\ast f\ast\overline{f}]$ and $[\gamma']=[\gamma'\ast f\ast\overline{f}]$ but now note that $\gamma\ast f$ and $\gamma'\ast f$ are paths from $x$ to $y$ and so by using the first part we get

$$\begin{array}{rcl}[\gamma][\gamma'] & = &[\gamma\ast f\ast\overline{f}][\gamma'\ast f\ast\overline{f}]\\
&=&[(\gamma\ast f)\ast\overline{f}][(\gamma'\ast f)\ast\overline{f}]\\
&=&[(\gamma'\ast f)\ast\overline{f}][(\gamma\ast f)\ast\overline{f}]\\
&=&[\gamma'][\gamma]\end{array}$$

and so $\pi_1(X,x)$ is abelian.

Comment: For the third equality, is it because $\gamma * f$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ and $\gamma^{\prime} * f * \bar{f}$ is a loop based at $x$? Then we use the fact that $[\gamma * f * \bar{f}] \in Z(\pi_1(X,x))$?

Comment: It's using the fact that an element of the form $[g\ast\overline{f}]$ is in the center of $\pi_1(X,x)$ and so we can swap the order of the two elements.

Comment: But is it true that $[(\gamma * f)*\bar{f}]$ is in the centre of $\pi_1(X,x)$?

Comment: Ah you edited your comment. Yes your above comment is right.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\gamma$ be a loop based at $x$, and suppose that you modify the path $f$, by concatenating it with the loop $\gamma$ to get a new path $g$.  How do the isomorphisms $u_f$ and $u_g$ differ?

Comment: So we have $g=\gamma * f$?

Comment: @Idonknow: Dear Idonknow, Yes, if I've understood your notation correctly.  Regards,